# Comparing data between two CSV files to move data to a third CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have this csv file, file1.csv:

```
OU    
CORP:Jenny Smith:
"CORP:John Smith:,John Smith:"
STORE:Mary Poppins:
STORE:Tony Stark: 
STORE:Carmen Sandiego:
NEWS:Peter Parker:
NEWS:Clark Kent:
STORES:store123:
NEWS:CORPmanager:
NEWS:STOREmanager:
ICECREAM:Will Ferrall:
SECURITY:James Bond:
SECURITY:Sherlock Holmes:
DELI:Brian Johnson:
""
```

Then file2.csv:

```
OU                      
CORP
STORE     
NEWS
ICECREAM
SECURITY
DELI
""
```

For every line in file2.csv that has 'CORP', 'STORE', or 'NEWS', I already searched through `file1.csv` and created a file, such as `STOREall.csv`, `CORPall.csv`, and `NEWSall.csv`.

I want OUs, such as `ICECREAM`, `SECURITY`, and `DELI` to be in the `CORPall.csv` file too.

So NEWSall.csv has:

```
OU  

NEWS:Peter Parker:   
NEWS:Clark Kent:  
NEWS:CORPmanager 
NEWS:STOREmanager
```

In CORPall.csv

```
OU 
CORP:Jenny Smith: 
CORP:John Smith:,John Smith: 
ICECREAM:Will Ferrall:
SECURITY:James Bond:
SECURITY:Sherlock Holmes:
DELI:Brian Johnson:
```

In STOREall.csv

```
OU    
STORE:Mary Poppins:
STORE:Tony Stark: 
STORE:Carmen Sandiego:
STORES:store123:
```

I am using Pandas and CSV in my program.
I used this snippet of code to move `STORE:` or `CORP:`, etc., to their corresponding files.
allOUs is all the OUs that go to `file2.csv`.

```
for dept in allOUs['OU']:
   df_dept = df[df['OU'].str.startswith(f'{dept}:')]

   df_dept['OU'].to_csv(f'{dept}all.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

This is the logic in my head of what I want to happen:

```
df_dept = df[df['OU'].str.startswith(f'{dept}:')]

if df_dept == "ICECREAM:" or df_dept == "SECURITY:" or df_dept == "DELI:":
   df_dept['OU'].to_csv('CORPall.csv', index=False, header=False)

else: #if everything else is not icecream, security or deli
   #move them normally to their self named files
   df_dept['OU'].to_csv(f'{dept}all.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using the header (`header=False`), you can check if `dept` is in the list of words that needs to be written to `CORP` file. Then, for the `CORP` file, you can use `to_csv` with argument `mode='a'`, which makes the data being written to be inserted at the end, after any preexisting data (of the `CORP` category).

```py
import pandas as pd

OUList = pd.DataFrame({'OU':['CORP', 'STORE', 'NEWS', 'ICECREAM', 'SECURITY', 'DELI']})

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep=';')

for dept in OUList['OU']:

    df_dept = df[df['OU'].str.startswith(f'{dept}:')]
    if dept in ["ICECREAM", "SECURITY", "DELI", "CORP"]:
        df_dept.to_csv(f'CORPall.csv', index=False, mode='a', header=False)
    else:
        df_dept.to_csv(f'{dept}all.csv', index=False, header=False)
```